# Tidymodels (Fitting Bagged Trees with 10-Fold Cross Validation in R): x Fold01: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL

Tags: machine-learning, tree, regression, tidymodels, bag

**Overview:**

I have produced four models using the tidymodels package with the **data frame FID** (see below):

1. General Linear Model
2. Bagged Tree
3. Random Forest
4. Boosted Trees

The data frame contains **three predictors**:

1. Year (numeric)
2. Month (Factor)
3. Days (numeric)

**The dependent variable is Frequency (numeric)**

**Issue**

I am attempting to fit the bagged tree model and I am experiencing this **error message below**:

**Any idea why I am getting an error when using bag_tree(), and fit_resamples()?**

There is not much material online, except I found this [post](http://https:/https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidymodels-logistic-reg-and-fit-resamples-error/55526); however, this problem relates to logistic regression, not bagged tree models.

```
x Fold01: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold02: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold03: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold04: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold05: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold06: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold07: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold08: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold09: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold10: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.

Warning message:

All models failed in [fit_resamples()]. See the `.notes` column.
```

If anyone can help with solving this error message, I would be deeply appreciative for your advice.

Many thanks in advance

**R-code**

```
##Open the tidymodels package
library(tidymodels)
library(glmnet)
library(parsnip)
library(rpart.plot)
library(rpart)
library(tidyverse) # manipulating data
library(skimr) # data visualization
library(baguette) # bagged trees
library(future) # parallel processing & decrease computation time
library(xgboost) # boosted trees
library(ranger)
library(yardstick)
library(purrr)
library(forcats)
library(rlang)
library(poissonreg)

#split this single dataset into two: a training set and a testing set
data_split <- initial_split(FID)
# Create data frames for the two sets:
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data  <- testing(data_split)

# resample the data with 10-fold cross-validation (10-fold by default)
cv <- vfold_cv(train_data, v=10)

###########################################################
##Produce the recipe

rec <- recipe(Frequency ~ ., data = FID) %>% 
          step_nzv(all_predictors(), freq_cut = 0, unique_cut = 0) %>% # remove variables with zero variances
          step_novel(all_nominal()) %>% # prepares test data to handle previously unseen factor levels 
          step_medianimpute(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes(), -has_role("id vars"))  %>% # replaces missing numeric observations with the median
          step_dummy(all_nominal(), -has_role("id vars")) # dummy codes categorical variables

#####Bagged Trees
mod_bag <- bag_tree() %>%
                    set_mode("regression") %>%
                          set_engine("rpart", times = 10) #10 bootstrap resamples

##Update the model with cost complexity  
##A positive number for the cost/complexity parameter, and 
##The cost/complexity parameter

Updated_bag<-update(mod_bag, cost_complexity=1)

##Create workflow
wflow_bag <- workflow() %>% 
                   add_recipe(rec) %>%
                        add_model(Updated_bag)

##Fit and predict the general linear model

bag_fit_model <- fit(wflow_bag, data = train_data)

##We can access the fit using pull_workflow_fit(), and even 
##tidy() the model coefficient results into a convenient dataframe format.
##STACKOVERFLOW
bag_fit_model %>%
       pull_workflow_fit() 

##Predict the model
bag_predict<-predict(bag_fit_model, train_data)

##Fit the model
plan(multisession)

fit_bag <- fit_resamples(
                      wflow_bag,
                      cv,
                      metrics = metric_set(rmse, rsq),
                      control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE,
                      extract = function(x) extract_model(x)))

x Fold01: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold02: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold03: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold04: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold05: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold06: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold07: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold08: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold09: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
x Fold10: model: Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.

Warning message:

All models failed in [fit_resamples()]. See the `.notes` column.
```

**Data Frame - FID**

```
structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), Month = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
"November", "December"), class = "factor"), Frequency = c(36, 
28, 39, 46, 5, 0, 0, 22, 10, 15, 8, 33, 33, 29, 31, 23, 8, 9, 
7, 40, 41, 41, 30, 30, 44, 37, 41, 42, 20, 0, 7, 27, 35, 27, 
43, 38), Days = c(31, 28, 31, 30, 6, 0, 0, 29, 15, 
29, 29, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 7, 0, 7, 30, 30, 31, 30, 27, 31, 
28, 30, 30, 21, 0, 7, 26, 29, 27, 29, 29)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cost_complexity` for decision trees is sometimes called [`alpha`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193538/how-to-choose-alpha-in-cost-complexity-pruning), and it should be a positive number smaller than one. Your model runs fine when you should a `cost_complexity` less than one:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(baguette)

FID <- structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
                               2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
                               2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                               2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), 
                      Month = structure(c(1L, 
                                          2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                          5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                          8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), 
                                        .Label = c("January", "February", "March", 
                                                   "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                                                   "November", "December"), class = "factor"), 
                      Frequency = c(36, 
                                    28, 39, 46, 5, 0, 0, 22, 10, 15, 8, 33, 33, 29, 31, 23, 8, 9, 
                                    7, 40, 41, 41, 30, 30, 44, 37, 41, 42, 20, 0, 7, 27, 35, 27, 
                                    43, 38), 
                      Days = c(31, 28, 31, 30, 6, 0, 0, 29, 15, 
                               29, 29, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 7, 0, 7, 30, 30, 31, 30, 27, 31, 
                               28, 30, 30, 21, 0, 7, 26, 29, 27, 29, 29)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                         -36L), class = "data.frame")

#split this single dataset into two: a training set and a testing set
data_split <- initial_split(FID)
# Create data frames for the two sets:
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data  <- testing(data_split)

# resample the data with 10-fold cross-validation (10-fold by default)
cv <- vfold_cv(train_data, v = 10)

rec <- recipe(Frequency ~ ., data = FID) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_predictors(), freq_cut = 0, unique_cut = 0) %>% # remove variables with zero variances
  step_novel(all_nominal()) %>% # prepares test data to handle previously unseen factor levels 
  step_medianimpute(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes(), -has_role("id vars"))  %>% # replaces missing numeric observations with the median
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -has_role("id vars")) # dummy codes categorical variables

mod_bag <- bag_tree(cost_complexity = 0.1) %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_engine("rpart", times = 10) #10 bootstrap resamples


wflow_bag <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(rec) %>%
  add_model(mod_bag)

fit(wflow_bag, data = train_data)
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: bag_tree()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 4 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> ● step_nzv()
#> ● step_novel()
#> ● step_medianimpute()
#> ● step_dummy()
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Bagged CART (regression with 10 members)
#> 
#> Variable importance scores include:
#> 
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    term             value std.error  used
#>    <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
#>  1 Days            4922.      369.     10
#>  2 Month_June      2253.      260.      9
#>  3 Month_July      1375.      139.      8
#>  4 Month_November   306.       96.4     3
#>  5 Year             272.      519.      2
#>  6 Month_May        270.      103.      4
#>  7 Month_February   191.      116.      4
#>  8 Month_August     105.       30.2     3
#>  9 Month_April       45.8      42.5     2
#> 10 Month_September   13.4       0       1
#> 11 Month_December    11.9       0       1
#> 12 Month_March       10.1       0       1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

I bet you tried a value of 1 because that is shown [in the docs here](https://baguette.tidymodels.org/reference/bag_tree.html), and this is very misleading. We'll get that fixed.

Comment: Hi Julia. Thank you for answering my question. When I added cost_complexity = 0.1 into the models, I experienced this warning message when I ran the model using the function fit_samples()

Comment: ! Fold02: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `estimate` is constant and has 0 sta...

Comment: Could I please ask what this warning message means and is there a way to fix it? Many thanks for your time and patience, I feel a lot of gratitude

Comment: I found a post that has this explanation: This can occur when the model predicts a single value for all samples. Two examples could be a regularized model that eliminates all predictors except the intercept and a CART tree that contains no splits.

Comment: I also had the same issue when I was trying to fit a random forest with the fit_samples() function: https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidymodels-fitting-random-forest-models-using-the-function-fit-samples-x-fold01-internal-error-must-group-by-variables-found-in-data/91109